# Search with or without space in django filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a search by name function, which should return the name of one person if the search matches the name.I need to show results with or without space between them. Eg: ‘A B C’ 
should show results A B Chacko, AB Chacko, AB Chaks etc. similarly, the search 
The term ‘ABC’ needs also list the above results.

```
try:
    term = request.GET['term']
    if term:
            queryset_primary = PrimaryUserSerializer(UserTable.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains =term)|Q(occupation__icontains=term)).order_by('name'), many=True, context=context).data
    else:
        pass
except:
    pass
```

The models only have the 'name ' field not have first name, last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code but this is very bad for performance.

```
    try:
        term = request.GET['term']
        if term:
                queryset_primary = PrimaryUserSerializer(UserTable.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains =term) | Q(name__istartswith=term) | Q(name__iexact=term) | Q(name__iendswith=term) | Q(name__startswith=trm)| Q(occupation__icontains=term)).order_by('name'), many=True, context=context).data
        else:
            pass

except:
    pass
```